# Error 'Access to the path is denied' al descargar imagen - Android

Tags: c#, android, android-studio, xamarin, android-permissions

Estoy teniendo error de acceso denegado cuando intento descargar una imagen desde mi app a la galeria del telefono.

Cabe destacar que el error me lo esta dando (de momento) solo con dispositivos con `Android 10` y que ya probe a pedirle los permisos explícitamente al iniciar la app y los muestra como "Granted" (adjunto imagen del punto de interrupción donde lo reviso).

Doc Path:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Pictures
```

Método para descarga de imagen (método donde da el error)

```
public void DescargarImagen(string URL)
        {
            try
            {
                var webClient = new WebClient();
                webClient.DownloadDataCompleted += (s, e) =>
                {
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[e.Result.Length];
                    bytes = e.Result; // get the downloaded data
                    string documentsPath = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures).AbsolutePath;

                    var partedURL = URL.Split('/');
                    string localFilename = partedURL[partedURL.Length - 1];                        
                    string localPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(documentsPath, localFilename);
                    File.WriteAllBytes(localPath, bytes); // Error

                    MediaScannerConnection.ScanFile(Application.Context, new string[] { localPath }, null, null);
                };
                var url = new Uri(URL);
                webClient.DownloadDataAsync(url);

            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                string LineErrorNumber = "Error en linea: " + Ex.StackTrace.Substring(Ex.StackTrace.Length - 7, 7) + "\r\n" + "Error: " + Ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Permisos:

```
readonly string[] PermisosParaPublicarImagenes =
        {
            Android.Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage,
            Android.Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage
        };
```

Peticion:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            try
            {
                RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
                base.OnCreate(bundle);
                this.SetContentView(Resource.Layout.InicioFeed);

                RequestPermissions(PermisosParaPublicarImagenes, PermisosHabilitados);
...
```

Resultado de petición con punto de interrupción (esta entrando en el if que evalua si ambos permisos = granted).

[image: Permisos otorgados]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desde `Android 10`, es posible que para poder "escribir" en el almacenamiento del dispositivo también se deba agregar el atributo android: `requestLegacyExternalStorage` al Android Manifest de la siguiente manera:

```
<application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" />
```

Comment: Esto soluciono mi error.